# How do I get all of my settings and documents back after updating from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: updates

I have a Dell Inspiron laptop recently updated from Ubuntu 16.04 to 16.10, and everything since is all gone; meaning no dash, unity, launcher, apps, etc.

Even my documents and files are missing! 
When I entered `sudo apt-get install gnome panel`, I got this response:

```
unable to locate package panel.
```

When I entered `

```
apt-get update
apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install unity
shutdown -r now
```

nothing changes.

So how do I fix this, and get back my Calibre & Kindle libraries, all my photos, music, and documents? Or are they gone forever?

P.S. I also don't have a Windows OS installed on the c drive, since I think I erased it by accident when I installed Ubuntu.

Comment: Please describe, in great detail, exactly how you told your system to upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10. Please also describe *using as much detail as possible* any error messages or warnings that you saw and when during the process you saw them.

Comment: The software updater told my system that some of my apps/files needed updating. After I clicked the button to let the system do that, it then told me that my computer needed to get re-started. Which was how I found out that I must have done something wrong because everything from 16.4 was mssing! I realize now that I should have looked at the  files that they felt should be updated, or I would not have the problems that I'm having now. P.S. There were no error messages or warnings that I can recall.

Comment: You can reply to requests for information by editing your original question, to keep all the info in one place.  So you ran software updater from the running 16.04 system, not from the install media?

Comment: Did the system, by chance, offer you a 'partial upgrade'? How long did the upgrade take before rebooting? You said 'nothing happens' when you tried to install Unity - what is the *exact response* from the system? Can you boot into an older kernel at GRUB?

Comment: What happens if you log into the Guest account? Start new comments directed at me with `@heynnema` or I may miss them.

Comment: @ubfan1that is correct

Comment: @user535733: the upgrade was fast, my wallpaper appeared with a 'scopes' menu that showed system settings and a terminal button. When I asked for help from ububtu, I couldn't do that because my internet connection was not recognized by 16.10. I now have the one browser app that gets me online. About your grub question. I don't know how to try that step. But if you would give me instructions on how to do that, I'll try it.

Comment: @heynnema: I couldn't get anywhere when I tried logging in using a guest account. I wonder if it'll be okay to try reinstalling Ubuntu using the cd I used from the beginning? Also, since I'm a complete novice using linux, maybe I should switch to a more Windows-type distro like Zorin? Esp since I've been having such a hard time adjusting to the Unity interface. Any suggestions would be welcomed.

Comment: When you logged into the Guest account, did it act normal? I mean the dash, unity, launcher, apps? If so, then the basic Ubuntu is working fine... and there's hope to recover your original stuff. Now try logging into your normal account, and type `control-alt-t` and see if a terminal window appears. If so, enter the command `pwd` and enter, then `ls /home`, then `ls Documents` and copy/paste the output into your original question. If `control-alt-t` doesn't bring up the terminal, try `control-alt-f1` and if that work, you'll need to log in at the prompts, and then do the 3 previous commands.

Comment: ps: stick with Ubuntu. Consider the launcher like the Start menu in Windows. The dash is like the search function. The top panel is like your system tray. It'll all become extremely easy once you get used to it... and it has a lot less problems than Windows or other Linux distros.

Comment: @heynnema. As I stated earlier, I could NOT start a guest session. I just know that the gnome/unity interface were all gone, and Abuntu 16.10 was now installed rather than 16.4 LTS. So, can I get these features back if I do a reinstalion of 16.4? Or what you advised in your answer to my question?

Comment: Just to be clear... you could NOT log into the Guest account from the main login window? And you could NOT get to one of the two terminals that I outlined earlier? If that's the case, reinstall 16.10 using a 16.10 Ubuntu Live DVD/USB, and if you uncheck the **format** box, it'll keep your current /home directory.

Comment: @heynnema: update. Tried reinstalling 16.10 but ran into partitioning issues. Also, I cannot access my files in my home folder, since I no longer have permission to do that. And I'm now a super user, and no longer see my original log-in name. So now I'm even more confused, and just want to go back to Windows 7. But I would like to get to my files before I take this step. Can you give me a detailed way to do this? And how do I make this post visible to more forum members? P.S. I wasn't kidding: I am a complete novice when it comes to anything computer-related. I'm trying, though!

Comment: How did you become a super user? Is this when booted to the Ubuntu Live DVD? If you boot to the Ubuntu Live DVD, can you view the /home folder on your hard disk? If so, do you see your username there? Tell me about the partitioning issues that you ran into. Edit your question to include a current-window-only screenshot of `gparted` and I'll take a look. Note that very soon they'll force us to move to a chat room to continue our conversation.

Comment: @heynnema: Thank you for all your help. Somebody will be coming by today to fix this mess for me hopefully.